# Branch.Io with Cordova Branch.loadRewards() no results

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, branch.io

Fowllowing Branch.Io documentation (https://dev.branch.io/features/referral-programs/guide/cordova/) I have implemented this code to get the reward credit balance of the current user:

This code returns rewards = 0

```
Branch.loadRewards().then(function (rewards) {
  console.log("rew", rewards);
  // will return the balance of the current user's credits
  $scope.credits = rewards['beer'];
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

But there should be one credit. This code returns it correctly:

```
Branch.creditHistory().then(function (credits) {
  console.log("cred", credits);
  // will return the balance of the current user's credits
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

[image: console.log]

Is my code wrong or is there an issue with Branch.Io cordova documentation / implementation?

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: there may be some sort of issue with `loadRewards` on a custom bucket in Cordova — it does seem to work with the default bucket when I test that. Could you [submit a ticket](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) to our Integrations team? They'll be able to track down whether this is a bug or a code issue.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the quick reply. You are right, the issue is linked to the bucket, if I use the default bucket it works fine. Although not as described in the documentation:

loadRewards() returns an integer with the number of credits in the default bucket.

According to the docs it should return an array or object with the different buckets.

Comment: That's what I was seeing also. Could be that something changed recently and we missed it. I see your support ticket in the queue, so hopefully we'll have an answer soon!

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch here: it looks like this was never properly implemented in our Cordova SDK, but the good news is we merged in a fix for it last night! The NPM module should be updated later today.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the quick solution. I understand that the correct use would now be loadRewards(bucket) ? Or is it as described in the documentation? What happens if I don't specify a bucket?

Comment: I haven't actually had a chance to test it for myself yet, but I believe this fix should have just made it so that your original code (matching the documentation) works as expected. If you don't specify anything, it would use the `default` bucket.